# How replace input name in Laravel validation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 5.8.

I have this code:

```
<form {{ $novalidate  }} method="post" name="contactformXX"
action="{{ route('adminHome') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field()  }}
<input type="text" value="{{ $user->vanessa_link1  ?? old('form_link1')}}"
name="form_link1" maxlength="150">
</form>
```

I show error with this code:

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="row alert alert-danger">
<li>Uzupełnij poprawnie wszystkie wymagane
pola! {{ $errors->first() }}</li>
</div>
@endif
```

When I post empty form I have error:

```
"Uzupełnij poprawnie wszystkie wymagane pola! Format form link1 jest nieprawidłowy."
```

How can I replace name input traditional name: "form link1" => "facebook url"?

Comment: How does your validation code look like?

Comment: What is the question? It's pretty unclear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller you are using validation to check variables,
Validator allow 3rd parameter which is messages
it should be something like

```
$this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);
```

or

```
Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
```

in $messages you can add:

```
$messages = [
form_link1.format_rule /* format_rule - name of validation rule ex. link1.url */ => trans('validation.rule_name', ['attribute' => 'facebook url']];
```

Comment: you think about something like this: $messages = [
           'form_link1' => trans('form_link1', ['attribute' => 'facebook url'])
        ];
                'form_link1'   => 'url',
                'form_link2'   => 'url',
                'form_link3'   => 'url',
                'form_link4'   => 'url',
            ], $messages);??

Comment: form_link1.url = trans('validation.url', ['attribute' => 'facebook url'])

Answer (score 0):

f you would like the `: attribute` portion of your validation message to be replaced with a custom attribute name, you may specify the custom name in the `attributes` array of your `resources/lang/xx/validation.php` language file:

So your validation.php may look like

```
'attributes' => [
    'form_link1' => 'form link',
],
```